# How to change from the Unity DE to Xfce? (Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Tags: unity, software-installation, xfce, desktop-environments

I've been trying to install the Xfce Desktop Environment more than once, with no success.

I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

(separately)

and then logged out and in again... but nothing changed, as I had no option to choose between two Desktop Environments.

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should see a small ubuntu logo next to your username on the log-in screen. When clicking it, a drop down menu should present you with the selection of all installed DEs. make your choice and enter your username/password after that.

Comment: If you don't see it after logout, try reboot as @Ciro Santilli suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 17.10**

This is how it looks like on Ubuntu 17.10:

[image]

I had to reboot after installing XFCE, a simple logout was not enough.